# Applet error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/ProxyGenerator

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I am running an applet from browser and am getting error:

```
    sun/misc/ProxyGenerator
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/ProxyGenerator
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.annotationForMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.AnnotationMapper$UnprocessedTypesSet.add(AnnotationMapper.java:481)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.AnnotationMapper$UnprocessedTypesSet.add(AnnotationMapper.java:466)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.AnnotationMapper.processAnnotations(AnnotationMapper.java:142)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.processAnnotations(XStream.java:1576)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.processAnnotations(XStream.java:1587)
    at com.plugin.PluginReader.getOptionalColumnsPluginPOJO(PluginReader.java:242)
    at com.applet.GUIValuesApplet.getOptionalColumns(GUIValuesApplet.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I run this applet from eclipse, it runs fine. I suspect there may be issue with jre version or accessing rt.jar in jre runtime. This is not code related issue for sure as everything was working until my system got restarted (it reboots per company policy on weekend). Therefore, any setting may have been changed.

Browser used: Chrome
latest version of jre on machine: jre7
code compiled using: jre6

Kindly respond as I have been facing this issue for long time now.

UPDATE:
Just to add, I get this error when I try to read xml file to Java class using annotaions in thoughtworks xstream lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks my jre installation got corrupt. I reinstalled it and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

sun.misc is a vendor specific class which should not be used in portable Java code.

Either make the code portable or switch the browser plugin to the Oracle JVM.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I checked my version using https://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp and it shows that I have latest recommended version i.e. Java 7. I believe the only requirement is to have latest java version installed and chrome will automatically pick it. Am I wrong? Last time it wasn't working with older version. Once I installed Java 7 it started working.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I am not calling sun.* packages directly from code. It is being invoked by java.lang only via xstream lib. I updated original post with full stack trace.